# How can i make the background paragraph color be over the background image?

Tags: pdf, libreoffice-writer, text-formatting, highlighting

I have this particular problem. My LibreOffice Write document has inserted a background image following the method proposed in their Q&A site (link in the comentaries), which reads as follows:

> Don't add it as a background for the page, as that is limited to the
>   printable area/the area defined by the page-margin.
>
> Instead
>
> - insert the graphic into the document,
> - choose **Anchor|To Page** from the contextmenu
> - choose **Wrap|In Background** from the contextmenu
>
> If the graphic should appear on all pages, insert a header or footer
>   and anchor the graphic to a paragraph or character in the header or
>   footer, then choose Picture from the contextmenu. On the Type tab, in
>   the Position section choose left/top to Entire Page. As with the
>   previous method, set wrap mode to "in background".

I wrote the text normally above the image, and then I tried to highlight part of the text by using the "background color" option in the paragraph menu, [as you can view here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uq4YH.png) When I go to print preview, or when I export it to PDF, [the highlight disappears.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VsWr.png)

The reason I know that the highlight is *behind* the background image, is because when I read the PDF in my very-old-much-slower netbook, I watched the page as it rendered, and the grey background textboxes were rendered before the image, and the text after those. Hard to replicate and take a screenshot while at it.

So my question breaks into two parts.
How can I make the background paragraph color be over the background image?
If this is negative, then:
Is there a workaround I can use to highlight a part of the text and have it rendered over the background image?

Comment: Since I cannot put more than 2 links due to my lack of reputation, here is [the link](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/4683/full-a4-background-image-in-writer/) for the Q&A.